# Extract text from a string and store in a variable

Tags: linux, bash

I have a string like `/feature/abc-1245_branch_name`, I wanted to extract abc-1245 from the string and store it into a different variable.

I tried using sed but didn't worked out well.

Comment: Will an underscore always follow the string you need extracted?  Will there ever be more than one directory before it?

Comment: Is the existing string also in a variable?  What defines the boundaries of your result? "After the second forward slash until the first underscore"? Something else?

Comment: For future questions, don't just say "it didn't work". Rather, show what you tried, and explain what unexpected result you got.

Comment: What is the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried grep and it worked very well and it is pretty simple.

```
$(echo "feature/ABC-BranchName" | grep -Eo 'develop|release|((feature|bugfix|hotfix)/ABC-)([0-9]+)' |tr '/' '-');
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk` (depending on how little variation your input string can have):

```
awk -F[_/] '{print $3}' <<<"$string"
```

If you want to be able to handle more complex directory structures you could use basename first

```
basename "$string" | awk -F_ '{print $1}'
```

To store in a variable use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)

```
variable=$(awk -F[_/] '{print $3}' <<<"$string")
```

Answer (score 5):

```bsh
string=/feature/abc-1245_branch_name

different_variable=${string%%_*}
different_variable=${different_variable##*/}

printf '%s\n' "$different_variable"
```

This uses standard parameter substitutions to first remove the bit after the first underscore, and then the bit before the last slash.

- `${variable%%pattern}` removes the longest substring matching `pattern` from the *end* of `$variable`.
- `${variable##pattern}` removes the longest substring matching `pattern` from the *start* of `$variable`.

---

If you know what `_branch_name` actually is,

```bsh
string=/feature/abc-1245_branch_name

different_variable=$( basename "$string" '_branch_name' )

printf '%s\n' "$different_variable"
```

This treats the string as a pathname (even though it may not be an actual pathname), and uses `basename` to get the last path component (i.e. "the filename").  The `basename` utility is also able to remove a filename suffix, so we use that to remove the known string `_branch_name`.

Answer (score 0):

And since no answer yet is based on `sed` and you asked for it;

```
$ string="/feature/abc-1245_branch_name"
$ sed -e 's/^.*\///; s/_.*$//' <<<"$string"
abc-1245
```

Use command substitution as @jesse_b suggests to put the result into a variable:

```
$ result=$(sed -e 's/^.*\///; s/_.*$//' <<<"$string")
$ echo $result
abc-1245
```

However, unless your string becomes a lot more complex to parse and parsing/filtering patterns change from string to string, i would use @kusalananda's pure Bash solution. It does the exact same thing as I do here with `sed`, i.e. greedy pattern matching, but in this simple case, pure Bash is probably the "natural" choice.